# Need help posting AJAX call to Rails using Gridster plugin

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, gridster

I'm trying to make my first jQuery AJAX post.  This is my first time working with JSON as well.  Please bear with me.

Since I don't know how to get the ID of the record into the url string, I've added a method to the crud controller, called 'move' and placed this line in the routes file:

```
post 'tickets/move' => 'tickets#move'
```

In the tickets controller

```
  # POST ajax method
  def move
    @ticket = Ticket.find params[:id]
    if @ticket.update(ticket_params)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { 
          render :json => { :row => @ticket.row, 
                            :col => @ticket.col } }
      end
    else
      false
    end
  end
```

the view

```
<div class="contentWrapper">
  <div class="gridster">
    <ul>
      <% @tickets.each do |ticket| %>
        <li class="gridster-cell" data-row="<%= ticket.row %>" data-col="<%= ticket.col %>" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"><%= ticket.customer %></li>

       <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the javascript, which keeps saying it fails

```
    // $(document).ready(function() {

$(document).on('ready page:load', function () {

    var gridster = $(".gridster > ul").gridster({
    widget_margins: [10, 10],
    widget_base_dimensions: [280, 420],
      min_cols: 7,
      min_rows: 7,
      extra_cols: 100,
      extra_rows: 50,

    serialize_params: function ($w, wgd) {
      return {
        //id: wgd.el[0].id,

        id: $($w).attr('id'),
        col: wgd.col,
        row: wgd.row
      }
    },

   // widget_selector: ".gridster",

    draggable: {
       //  handle: ".gridster-cell"
        stop: function(e, ui, $widget) {
          var positions = JSON.stringify($(this).serialize());
  // var positions = JSON.stringify( $(".gridster > ul").gridster().data('gridster')).serialize();
         // localStorage.setItem('positions', positions);

          $.ajax({
            //url: $(this).attr('action'),
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            url: "/tickets/move.json",
            data: positions,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            error: function(data) {   alert("failure");  },
            success: function(data) { alert("success");  }
          });
        }
      } 



  }).data('gridster');
  gridster.enable();
});
```

Here is the error. It's passing nothing to the rails controller:

```
Started POST "/tickets/move.json" for ::1 at 2015-01-30 13:44:10 -0600
Processing by TicketsController#move as JSON
  Parameters: {"_json"=>"", "ticket"=>{}}
  Ticket Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "tickets".* FROM "tickets" WHERE "tickets"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Ticket with 'id'=):
```

I need to save the layout for the whole gridster board after any card is put into a new position.  But first I need to figure out how to make this ajax call work.  Thank you kindly for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve list buy using this code

public ActionResult DashBoardPosition(List positions)
        {

```
        return Json("");
    }
    public class DashboardGrid
    {
        public int  col { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public int row { get; set; }
        public int Sizex { get; set; }
        public int Sizey { get; set; }

    }
```